# TYPO3 call a class from controller

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I wanna call a seperate Class from my Controller.

The class is found under: Classes/Domain/Services
I wanna call only a getter!

The class I wanna call is named TestClass.php

In my controller I tried: `$this->view->assign('options', $this->TestClass->getTest());`

The Testclass looks like this:

```
class NoteArrays {
    protected $tests= array(        
       'a' => 'a',        
       'b' => 'b');

    public function getTest() {        
       return $this->tests;   
    }
}
```

But I've got only a blank page....

Comment: i've also tried it this way:


`namespace Test\Test\Services\NestedDirectory;
class NoteArrays {
    protected $tests= array(        
       'a' => 'a',        
       'b' => 'b');

    public function getTest() {        
       return $this->tests;   
    }
}`

`$array = new \Test\Test\Services\NestedDirectory\NoteArrays();`


`$this->view->assign('options', $array->getTest());`

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!! like in the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soution is:

```
namespace Test\Test\Services\NestedDirectory; 

class NoteArrays { 

       protected $tests= array( 'a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b'); 

       public function getTest() { 
             return $this->tests; 
       } 
}
```

And to create and assign:

```
$array = new \Test\Test\Services\NestedDirectory\NoteArrays(); 
$this->view->assign('options', $array->getTest());
```